# If else statement, if its successful continue, else wait and try again

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement

So I have been trying to play around with the function in Selenium that is called:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='nsg-button nsg-bg--black register-next-step-cta js-nextStepCta' and contains(.,'FORTSÄTT')]")))
```

Before I'm starting to say the issue. What I'm trying to do a Selenium of is to basically make a Selenium that automatic write to the forumlar in this picture:

[image: Pic1]

Which isn't any complications. However whenever I press "Skapa Konto", It loads and waits until a new page comes up which is:

[image: Pic2]

But the issue is that sometimes it gets and error and gives a picture that is saying:

[image: Pic3]

Basically what I need to do is to press Dismiss this error and press again on "SKAPA KONTO" with a random delay click between 1-10 secs and see if there is the same error or successful. Basically the idea is if its successful. Just continue do the rest of the script with works fine. And then whenever this error pops out. Press the Dismiss this error and press "SKAPA KONTO" again which is:

```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='CREATE ACCOUNT']")))
```

Update:

Stupid of me! So I forgot to add the HTML for the error which is:

```
<span class="nike-unite-h1-no-image">An error occurred.</span>
<input type="button" value="Dismiss this error">
```

So how would I make it possible that it retries until it gives me successful and continues the code?

Comment: Thanks @Filmzy for the edit! :)

Comment: What happens when you press `Dismiss this error`? Are you redirected back to the page with the button with text as **Skapa Konto**?

Comment: Correct @DebanjanB - All the information is the same as it was. Just need to re-press the *Skapa Konto* again :)

Comment: Basically meaning everything is still there, the exact same picture as it is in picture 1. So as I said, Just need to re-press **Skapa Konto** and retry with random delays click until its been successful :)

Comment: Please be specific :) my question is still unanswered :( What happens when you press `Dismiss this error`? Are you redirected back to the page with the button with text as _Skapa Konto_ ?

Comment: have you tried try catch concept here ?

Comment: Oh my bad. Yes you are getting redirected back to the page with that button with the text **Skapa konto** - Be in mind. It doesn't re-direct to a new page URL but it's still the same page URL. but you do see the **Skapa Konto** when you pressed the *Dismiss this Error*.

Comment: Be aware that you may not have permission to store information such as sex due to GDPR.

Comment: Oh! Yeah I did read about that. That shouldn't be an issue with that @Moberg but I do appreciate alot that you did say this! GDPR is still new learning phase for me! haha. But thanks!

Comment: @CDNthe2nd One more follow up question : As _you are getting redirected back to the page with that button with the text `Skapa konto`_ does the fields with data e.g. `CDNthe2nd@selenium.com`, `Hello`, `World` etc are retained properly? **Note** ; `if you don't add @DebanjanB in your replies I don't get notified if you have answered to my question`

Comment: @DebanjanB Oh yes. All the fields data is still there and retains properly. I hope I did tag you correctly now. Im sorry :) But yes. All data is still there properly! :)

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Dismiss this error** and then `click()` again on the element with text as **SKAPA KONTO**

```
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='nsg-button nsg-bg--black register-next-step-cta js-nextStepCta' and contains(.,'FORTSÄTT')]"))).click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Dismiss this error']").click()
        # replace the exact working locator strategy for this element from your end
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(.,'SKAPA KONTO')]"))).click()
```

Comment: I think your code will only run one iteration,  the `while True` is unnecessary.